# Is there any word for someone you just met?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, phrase-requests

Question says it all. I am looking for a word or phrase that describes someone you have just met. Context: I want to use this word to show that even (someone I just met) can tell that I am ___.

Comment: A recent acquaintance?

Comment: *Someone I just met* is idiomatic. Or *stranger* or *recent acquaintance*.

Comment: "newly acquainted".  you can use it like "Even newly acquainted  can tell that I am very sophisticated".

Comment: Thank you for the help guys :) The phrase that I really liked was "recent acquaintance".

Answer (score 3):

**Acquaintance**

Because Alex and I just met, we were merely acquaintances.

> a person one knows slightly, but who is not a close friend.

As [WS2](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/53966/ws2) suggested, you can use the term "recent acquaintance" to describe someone you met just recently.

[Source](https://www.google.com/search?q=acquaintance&)

Comment: As WS2 suggests, "*recent* acquaintance" is more suited to the OP's case.